# Is spatial reference information suceptible to be translated?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system, internationalization

In an English application that uses ArcObjects API from ESRI, the information regards the spatial reference system is displayed in English as the API gives it.

If the application is translated to another language (let's say Russian), the information regards the spatial reference should be translated too? I mean, terms like "Mercator", "Degrees", "Magna", "WGS1984UTM30N" should be translated?

Does any one know if this information appear in Cyrillic alphabet in ArcGIS in Russian? I wonder, Is there a Russian version of ArcGIS Desktop? if the answer is positive, how does it show the information of spatial reference systems?

Comment: The strings are UTF-8, but the keywords need to be in English.

Comment: You could use EPSG codes, they're numbers and should translate easily... as for what the numbers mean, that's a different thing altogether. Perhaps you could contact http://spatialreference.org/ and suggest translating some codes into your native language to make it easier for Russian speaking persons to use GIS software.